# Select rows with counts less than value for all dates

Tags: mysql

There is Mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB table:

```
id  date        count
1   17.10.2021  1
2   17.10.2021  1
3   17.10.2021  2

1   18.10.2021  1
2   18.10.2021  2
3   18.10.2021  3

1   19.10.2021  1
2   19.10.2021  1
3   19.10.2021  4
```

How to select only that id which has count < 2 for all dates ?

Expected result:

```
id
1
```

Comment: only < 2  (i.e 1)

Comment: Right, I did not read the sample data correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation and the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(count) < 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1259787ea11ca90cd5d8b2e6b7912ccf).
Results:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: Wouldn't this also return the id of 2 since id 2 has a count of 1 on 19.10.2021?
You would need to include the date in there somewhere.

Comment: @Rhuarc13 no, the date is not needed. I changed the condition to `< 2` instead of `<=2`

Comment: forpas, in case of 
"3   17.10.2021  1 "  id=3 is in result too. But i need only that id , which has count = 1   for every date.

Comment: @harp1814 id=3 is not in the results. Check the demo in my answer.